# how to set path for fsl in google colab

Tags: bash, image-processing, path, google-colaboratory

I am trying to do skull stripping using nipype fsl in colab
I have installed fsl in google colab but its last step requires to add following line in .bashrc file

```
FSLDIR=/usr/share/fsl
. ${FSLDIR}/5.0/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh
PATH=${FSLDIR}/5.0/bin:${PATH}
export FSLDIR PATH
```

after executing `!whereis` fsl command i am getting output as

> ```
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fnirt /usr/bin/fsl5.0-first_boundary_corr
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-viena_quant /usr/bin/fsl5.0-bedpostx_datacheck
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl2ascii /usr/bin/fsl5.0-probtrackx
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-extractfidparams /usr/bin/fsl5.0-asl_calib
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-aff2rigid /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Text2Vest
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fabber /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslswapdim
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-melodic /usr/bin/fsl5.0-imln /usr/bin/fsl5.0-pnm_evs
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-mcflirt /usr/bin/fsl5.0-lesion_filling
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-first /usr/bin/fsl5.0-vecreg /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Featquery
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-slicesmask /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fast
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-run_mesh_utils /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_2_reg
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-bet2 /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsladd
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-systemnoise /usr/bin/fsl5.0-create_lut
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tsplot /usr/bin/fsl5.0-robustfov
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-cutoffcalc /usr/bin/fsl5.0-feat_gm_prepare
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-surf2surf /usr/bin/fsl5.0-siena_flirt
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Possum /usr/bin/fsl5.0-distancemap
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-applywarp /usr/bin/fsl5.0-eddy_correct
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-drawmesh /usr/bin/fsl5.0-basil_var
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslvbm_3_proc /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_sbca
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_deproject /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslfft
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslcc /usr/bin/fsl5.0-mccutup
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-selfintersection /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_glm
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-surface_fdr /usr/bin/fsl5.0-generate_b0calc
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-pvmfit /usr/bin/fsl5.0-mm /usr/bin/fsl5.0-medianfilter
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl /usr/bin/fsl5.0-first_flirt
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-possum_matrix /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslmeants
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-standard_space_roi /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslcorrecthd
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-ccops /usr/bin/fsl5.0-randomise_parallel
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-siena_cal /usr/bin/fsl5.0-surf_proj
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-extracttxt /usr/bin/fsl5.0-possum
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_mvlm /usr/bin/fsl5.0-InvertXFM
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Make_flobs /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Renderstats
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-b0calc /usr/bin/fsl5.0-prewhiten
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-xfibres /usr/bin/fsl5.0-contrast_mgr
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslFixText /usr/bin/fsl5.0-dual_regression
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Susan /usr/bin/fsl5.0-updatefeatreg
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-epi_reg /usr/bin/fsl5.0-possumX
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-randomise /usr/bin/fsl5.0-eddy_combine
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslchpixdim /usr/bin/fsl5.0-AnatomicalAverage
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-pngappend /usr/bin/fsl5.0-surf2volume
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-dtigen /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_x
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslvbm_1_bet /usr/bin/fsl5.0-ptoz
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-ApplyXFM /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslcpgeom
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tcalc /usr/bin/fsl5.0-generate_brain
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-gps /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Pnm /usr/bin/fsl5.0-basil
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-find_the_biggest /usr/bin/fsl5.0-probtrackx2
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_gui /usr/bin/fsl5.0-slicer
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-convert_xfm /usr/bin/fsl5.0-asl_preproc
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-signal2image /usr/bin/fsl5.0-ConcatXFM
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_motion_outliers /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_histogram
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-pointflirt /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslsmoothfill
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-checkFEAT /usr/bin/fsl5.0-ztop
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_prepare_fieldmap /usr/bin/fsl5.0-applytopup
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-halfcosbasis /usr/bin/fsl5.0-swap_voxelwise
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslslice /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslchfiletype_exe
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-first_roi_slicesdir /usr/bin/fsl5.0-zeropad
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-featquery /usr/bin/fsl5.0-immv /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Fdt
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslerrorreport /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_skeleton
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-featregapply /usr/bin/fsl5.0-run_first
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-rmsdiff /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslhd
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-viena_createpng /usr/bin/fsl5.0-imrm
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_boxplot /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_sym
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-invwarp /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslvbm_2_template
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Feat /usr/bin/fsl5.0-slices
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fdt_rotate_bvecs /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslcomplex
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslanimate /usr/bin/fsl5.0-qboot_parallel
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-applyxfm4D /usr/bin/fsl5.0-mvntool
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_4_prestats /usr/bin/fsl5.0-bedpost
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-film_gls /usr/bin/fsl5.0-swap_subjectwise
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-mean /usr/bin/fsl5.0-invfeatreg
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-pairreg /usr/bin/fsl5.0-smoothest
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_abspath /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslchfiletype
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-oxford_asl /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslsurfacemaths
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-ttoz /usr/bin/fsl5.0-siena_diff
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-cluster /usr/bin/fsl5.0-std2imgcoord
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-slicesdir /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslinfo
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-baycest /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslsize
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-avscale /usr/bin/fsl5.0-slices_summary
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslecho /usr/bin/fsl5.0-susan /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Asl
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Bet /usr/bin/fsl5.0-invwarp_exe
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-concat_bvars /usr/bin/fsl5.0-asl_reg
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-topup /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Flirt
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-design_ttest2 /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fabber_var
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslmaths /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Renderhighres
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-quasil /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tmpnam /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslsplit
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-setFEAT /usr/bin/fsl5.0-sienax
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-remove_ext /usr/bin/fsl5.0-spharm_rm
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-siena /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslnvols
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslmodhd /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslroi
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslreorient2std /usr/bin/fsl5.0-feat
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fnirtfileutils /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslstats
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-proj_thresh /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_regfilt
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-avw2fsl /usr/bin/fsl5.0-imglob
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-filmbabescript /usr/bin/fsl5.0-easythresh
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_schurprod /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_fill
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-setup_masks /usr/bin/fsl5.0-qboot
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-pnm_stage1 /usr/bin/fsl5.0-filmbabe
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Fsl_prepare_fieldmap /usr/bin/fsl5.0-renderhighres
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Melodic /usr/bin/fsl5.0-feat_model
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-maskdyads /usr/bin/fsl5.0-flirt_average
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_tsplot /usr/bin/fsl5.0-asl_mfree
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-calc_grad_perc_dev /usr/bin/fsl5.0-first3Dview
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_reg /usr/bin/fsl5.0-select_dwi_vols
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-mainfeatreg /usr/bin/fsl5.0-sliceanimate
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-hist2prob /usr/bin/fsl5.0-imtest
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-match_smoothing /usr/bin/fsl5.0-possum_sum
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-first_utils /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslinterleave
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-img2imgcoord /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslascii2img
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-cluster2html /usr/bin/fsl5.0-siena_flow2std
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-ttologp /usr/bin/fsl5.0-betsurf /usr/bin/fsl5.0-pulse
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-connectedcomp /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsledithd
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslselectvols /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fdr
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_sub /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslcreatehd
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-generate_b0 /usr/bin/fsl5.0-unconfound
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-new_invwarp /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_3_postreg
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-convertwarp /usr/bin/fsl5.0-autoaq
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-verbena /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslval
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-tbss_non_FA /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fugue
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fsl_anat /usr/bin/fsl5.0-label2surf
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-wpng /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Nudge
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-first_mult_bcorr /usr/bin/fsl5.0-asl_file
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Vest2Text /usr/bin/fsl5.0-makerot
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-overlay /usr/bin/fsl5.0-sigloss
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-prelude /usr/bin/fsl5.0-dtifit
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-probtrack /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslpspec
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-estnoise /usr/bin/fsl5.0-flirt
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-slicetimer /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslorient
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-bet /usr/bin/fsl5.0-generateConfounds
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-imcp /usr/bin/fsl5.0-perfusion_subtract
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-morph_kernel /usr/bin/fsl5.0-make_dyadic_vectors
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslswapdim_exe /usr/bin/fsl5.0-run_first_all
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-img2stdcoord /usr/bin/fsl5.0-old_betall
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-flameo /usr/bin/fsl5.0-ftoz /usr/bin/fsl5.0-midtrans
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Glm /usr/bin/fsl5.0-popp /usr/bin/fsl5.0-fslmerge
> /usr/bin/fsl5.0-Fast /usr/bin/fsl5.0-whirlgif /usr/lib/fsl /etc/fsl
> /usr/share/fsl /usr/share/man/man1/fsl.1.gz
> ```

Comment: Maybe this is relevant troubleshooting information, but can you tell us what your actual problem is?

Comment: fsl.bet().run() is giving error as "No command "bet" found on host c4db105cafd7. Please check that the corresponding package is installed."   but i have installed fsl inside usr/share/fsl

Comment: Next question: what does `which bet` output on your system?

Comment: output is blank

Comment: So that means `bet` is not actually installed yet, or else you didn't add it to your path. You need to research how to install and configure `bet`. I can't help you with that part, I've never heard of or used that software.

Comment: If this is part of nipype fsl, though, this page shown that there are preconfigure docker images you can use, as well as conda packages, that might be easier if it pre-handles all the dependencies for you. https://nipype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install.html